# I read data from database using js, but I do not know why the function "display_info" does not work. what is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, html

I checked everything and it works correctly up to display_info() function. But I couldn't understand where is the problem and why it doesn't show me the info?

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="">
            <label for="select-tag">Choose your favorite movie: </label>
            <select name="select-tag" id="select" class="" onchange="display_info(this)"></select>
        </form>

        <div id="info-div" class="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var all_data;

        function display_title() {

            var select_tag = document.getElementById("select");
            for (let i = 0 ; i < all_data.length ; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
                option.innerHTML = all_data[i].title + "(" + all_data[i].year + ")";
                option.value = all_data[i].id;
                select_tag.appendChild(option);
            }
        }
        
        async function read_data(path) {
            var x = await fetch(path);
            var y = await x.text();
            all_data = JSON.parse(y);
            for (let i = 0 ; i < all_data.length ; i++) {
                all_data[i].id = i+1;
            }
            display_title();
            // console.log(all_data);
        }

        function display_info(movie) {
            var div = document.getElementById("info-div");
            div.innerHTML = "";
            for (let i = 0 ; i < all_data.length ; i++) {
                if (movie.id == all_data[i].id) {
                    var title = document.createElement("H3");
                    var p = document.createElement("P");
                    title.innerHTML = movie.title + "(" + movie.year + ")";
                    p.innerHTML = movie.info;
                    div.appendChild(title);
                    div.appendChild(p);
                }
            }
        }
        

        read_data("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/farzadForoozanfar/Website-design-programming/main/Assignment18(IMDB)/moviedata.json");


    </script>
</body>
```

Did I made a mistake in passing arguments to the function "display_info"?

What should I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple mistakes in your code.
The function call was fine (even though it's generally better to separate the js code from the html code; I encourage you to read about it). The first error is that `this` was refering to the `select` element and not the selected option.

Then there was a useless loop and condition. You directly have the movie ID in the `index` of the selected movie `option`. It was also pointless to recreate the title + date string, since it is the `label` of the selected `option`.

Then there was a confusion with the object that was containing the movie infos.
Finally, the infos were a JSON object, that's why I've roughly used `JSON.stringify`.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="">
      <label for="select-tag">Choose your favorite movie: </label>
      <select name="select-tag" id="select" class="" onchange="display_info(this)"></select>
    </form>

    <div id="info-div" class="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var all_data;

    function display_title() {

      var select_tag = document.getElementById("select");
      for (let i = 0; i < all_data.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        option.innerHTML = all_data[i].title + "(" + all_data[i].year + ")";
        option.value = all_data[i].id;
        select_tag.appendChild(option);
      }
    }

    async function read_data(path) {
      var x = await fetch(path);
      var y = await x.text();
      all_data = JSON.parse(y);
      for (let i = 0; i < all_data.length; i++) {
        all_data[i].id = i + 1;
      }
      display_title();
      // console.log(all_data);
    }

    function display_info(select) {
      var movie = select.selectedOptions[0];
      var div = document.getElementById("info-div");
      div.innerHTML = "";
      var title = document.createElement("H3");
      var pre = document.createElement("PRE");
      title.innerHTML = movie.text;
      pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(all_data[movie.index].info, null, 3);
      div.appendChild(title);
      div.appendChild(pre);
    }
    read_data("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/farzadForoozanfar/Website-design-programming/main/Assignment18(IMDB)/moviedata.json");
  </script>
</body>
```